Parse HTML JSON output
I have the following HTML output I'd like to parse as JSON in python
window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = JSON.parse('{\"deviceType\":\"desktop\",\"session\":{\"cmpEnabled\":false,\"showAds\":true,\"logClientMetrics\":false,\"fringeEnabled\":true,\"features\":[\"song_stories_public_launch\"]},\"currentPage\":\"songPage\",\"songPage\":{\"longTailCacheExperiment\":null,\"song\":4779945,\"pinnedQuestions\":[],\"metadataQuestions\":[\"producer:song:4779945\",\"release-date:song:4779945\",\"writer:song:4779945\"],\"lyricsData\":{\"referents\":[],\"body\":{\"html\":\"<p>[Intro]<br>\\n(1,2,3,4)<br>\\nHey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey<br>\\nHey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey<br>\\n<br>\\n[Verse 1]<br>\\nHey (Hey), I\'m your life, I\'m the one who takes you there<br>\\

I've tried with beautifuloup and using a regular expression but didn't get the desired results.  I'd like to use json.loads in Python to convert what's inside window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = JSON.parse to a dictionary.

What have you tried exactly and how didn't that work?

If you have that string and want to capture the json substring, it looks like you might be able to slice it, however we can't advise you until we have a string the represents a complete json payload. That string does not have the full json.

Does this answer your question? RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags

Could you try the following code? It should return a JSON response:
import json
import re

html_content = """
window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = JSON.parse('{\"deviceType\":\"desktop\",\"session\":{\"cmpEnabled\":false,\"showAds\":true,\"logClientMetrics\":false,\"fringeEnabled\":true,\"features\":[\"song_stories_public_launch\"]},\"currentPage\":\"songPage\",\"songPage\":{\"longTailCacheExperiment\":null,\"song\":4779945,\"pinnedQuestions\":[],\"metadataQuestions\":[\"producer:song:4779945\",\"release-date:song:4779945\",\"writer:song:4779945\"],\"lyricsData\":{\"referents\":[],\"body\":{\"html\":\"<p>[Intro]<br>\\n(1,2,3,4)<br>\\nHey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey<br>\\nHey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey, hey<br>\\n<br>\\n[Verse 1]<br>\\nHey (Hey), I\\'m your life, I\\'m the one who takes you there<br>\\n\"}}}}');
"""

pattern = re.compile(r"""window\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = JSON\.parse\('(.*?)'\);""", re.DOTALL)

match = pattern.search(html_content)
if match:
    json_str = match.group(1)
    print("Extracted JSON string:", json_str)  
    json_str = json_str.replace('\\n', '\\\\n').replace('\\\'', '\\\\\'')
    
    try:
        data = json.loads(json_str) 
        print(data)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Failed to decode JSON: {e}")
else:
    print("No JSON found")


Since your answer guards for invalid json, why modify their json to make it valid?

That's a legit question. Assuming the source HTML content cannot be fixed, it should be addressed afterwards.
